# How do I check the type of my JQuery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute a function on the condition that the input triggering it isn't of type submit.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//triggers the capture() function whenever any input on the page loses focus
$("input").blur(function() {

// This is the part that's not working. I need to check if the specific input that 
// triggered the code to run is of type submit. 

if (("input").type == 'submit') {
    alert("this worked");
}
else {

    capture();

}
});

});
```

Right now capture() is being called even when I blur an input of type submit.  I want this code to trigger the first conditional statement when an input of type submit is what triggers the outer function to run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery will assign the value of `this` inside the event callbacks to be the element that the event was triggered for, so you can access its properties with that:

```
if (this.type === 'submit') {
    // ...
} else {
    // ...
}
```

<sub>(At least up until another `function` is involved, as that'll have its own `this` value.)</sub>

The condition you have currently is testing the property of the string, `"input"`, which will likely be `undefined` and not equal to `'submit'`.

---

Though, if you just want to exclude submit buttons entirely, you could also use the selector for that using [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and jQuery's custom [`:submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) selectors.

```
$('input:not(:submit)').blur(capture);
```

Comment: I like the second option, more elegant =)

Answer (score 3):

Use the attr method with 'type' like this

```
if($(this).attr('type') === 'submit'){

}
```

Comment: this wouldn't work if somebody had this as their html <button>Submit</submit>

Comment: Then that wouldn't be a submit input type... or explain better :)

Comment: @VtoCorleone your example doesn't have a type of submit, which is what the question asks for

Comment: @aw04 - chrome defaults buttons without a specified type to submit.  Not sure about the other browsers.  Either way, it's not a guarantee that the type will be specified.

Comment: Interesting, but the developer should make sure to add it, but is good to know that.

Comment: @VtoCorleone In this case, the selector being used already excludes `<button>`s. But, yes, its `type` property would be `submit` by default, while the attribute can be empty.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - ::facepalm:: - I went into my own zone with the button.  Reading comprehension fail on my part.